# How to read bean from other xml file (Spring)

Tags: spring

I have declared a bean in `student.xml` file:

```
<bean id="student1" class="com.raykor.hello.Spring3HelloWorld">
    <property name="name" value="Sachin" />
     <property name="age" value="25" />
    </bean>
```

and now i want to use it into another file. Is it possible to use beans from another file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import it from another Spring config file, yes, e.g.:

```
<beans>
    <import resource="config-file-in-same-dir.xml"/>

    <import resource="../config-file-in-parent-dir.xml"/>
</beans>
```

then you should be able to reference beans defined in your imported config files as if they were defined in that very file.